# goo.gl vs Google Analytics huge data discrepancy?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

goo.gl link created 5 days ago. received 2601 clicks to date.

GA account only showing 399 hits for the entire month for the page it directs traffic to on the site. Link received 1000 hits in first day and is well past 24-48 data delay for GA account.

All tracking codes are correct on site.

Can anyone think of a reason there is such a huge deference in these figures?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it basically a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729697/javascript-analytics-conversion-script-expected-failure-rate (and is also off-topic). A relevant considerations for both question is that Google Analytics does not measure raw clicks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/